# Using input parameter to init object inside JPA @Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to initialize my model through its constructor inside @Query using provided parameter.

I have tried named parameter but nothing is going to work. I have test some Spel too but it is not working as well. Most of the time, compile error. I have tried to google but could not find any related result.

I have create Person class as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
class Person{
    @Id
    private int age;
    private String name;

    Person(int age, String name)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, int>{

    @Query("SELECT new Person(:age, person.name) FROM Person person")
    List<Person> findAll(@Param("age") int age);   


    // also have tried this
    @Query("SELECT new Person(:#{#age}, person.name) FROM Person person")
    List<Person> findAll(@Param("age") int age);   

    // also have tried this
    @Query("SELECT new Person(?1, person.name) FROM Person person")
    List<Person> findAll(int age);   

      // also have tried this
    @Query("SELECT new Person(age1, person.name) FROM Person person, :age as age1")
    List<Person> findAll(@Param("age") age);   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing obvious errors in your code (no default constructor, primitive in type argument) first three methods throws during application startup:

```
QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [Person]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String
```

This this is because constructor accepts only select expressions as parameters, not parameter nodes and it is omitted. Adding casting to expression is solving above problem and code works as expected:

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{
  @Query("SELECT new Person(cast(:age as int), person.name) FROM Person person")
  List<Person> findAll(@Param("age") int age);  
}
```

Above approach is a workaround and this is causing argument to be send to db in sql (example in h2 dialect):

```
select cast(? as integer) as col_0_0_, person0_.name as col_1_0_ from person person0_
```

and is dependent on database cast function. Because of that you cannot pass there composite type (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9459)

Comment: Is this "cast" keyword a part of jpa? I could not find any document related to this.  <br/> 

And how about if I want to cast this as List<Children> how can I do that? I have this the following but i got error.  <br/>


<code>
class Person{
    ...
    public Person(List<Children> children){
        ...
    }
}

@Repository
interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{
  @Query("SELECT new Person(cast(:age as java.util.List<Children>)) FROM Person person")
  List<Person> findAll(@Param("children") List<Children> children);  
}
</code>

Comment: Cast is hibernate expression; from hibernate docs: "cast(... as ...), where the second argument is the name of a Hibernate type, and extract(... from ...) if ANSI cast() and extract() is supported by the underlying database". You should provide full class name with package, I don't know if this accept generic types - I would try providing class name without generics - @Query("SELECT new Person(cast(:age as java.util.List)) FROM Person person")

Comment: I have tried this too but it's not working at all. I either thinking of casting it to Object and then convert it back to List<Children> in Person constructor but no it is not working. Not sure if i did it wrong or so.

Comment: I've checked, and seems like this is not possible. I've edited my answer. Event if it would be possible, this parameter would be sent to db and I don't this this would be optimal.